# Understanding $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]

Tags: php

I'm following LARACAST PHP practitioner classes and I had a problem with $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI].

It always returns 404 not found if I write in browser for url: `localhost/laracast/about` and I have in router->define just `'laracast' => 'controllers/index.php'` , or some other page after laracast/ except index. I had to change it to `localhost/laracast/index.php/about` to make it work, and every other page. I've lost all day figuring out this and I still don't understand why it simply doesn't throw an exception I've declared in class if I omit index.php in my routes rather than 404 error. Does it have something with server or what?

The code is next:

routes.php

```
$router->define([

'laracast/index.php' => 'controllers/index.php',
'laracast/index.php/about' => 'controllers/about.php',
'laracast/index.php/about/culture' => 'controllers/about-culture.php',
'laracast/index.php/contact' => 'controllers/contact.php']);
```

Router class

```
class Router
{

    private $routes = [];

    public function define($routes){
        $this->routes = $routes;
    }

    public static function load($file){

        $router = new static;
        require $file;
        return $router;
    }


    public function direct($uri)

    {

        if(array_key_exists($uri, $this->routes)){

            return $this->routes[$uri];
        }

        throw new Exception("No route defined for this URI");

    }

}
```

and index.php

```
<?php 

$query = require 'core/bootstrap.php';

$uri = trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/');

require Router::load('routes.php')

        ->direct($uri);
```

With this url `http://localhost/laracast/index.php/about` it works just fine, and all the other pages preceded by index.php.
Any explanation and/or suggestions, or this is a valid solution?

Comment: you need to use `mod_rewrite` and dispatch the requests properly... so that `localhost/laracast/about` would become eg. `localhost/about`. see https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=htaccess

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Martin Zeitler instructions and doing some research I've make it work. In .htaccess file I've just added this peace of code.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

and now it recognizes routes.