# How to fix: RewriteRule not working in .htaccess

Tags: php, ajax, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Please consider the content in my `.htaccess`:

```
##
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

## Allow a few SEO Files direct access.
RewriteRule ^robots.txt?$ robots.txt [L]
RewriteRule ^ads.txt?$ ads.txt [L]
RewriteRule ^sellers.json?$ sellers.json [L]


## Avoid rewriting rules for the admin section
RewriteRule ^(admin|resources)($|/) - [L]

## Set Ajax Request File
RewriteRule ^(kahuk-ajax)/?$ kahuk-ajax.php? [L,QSA]

## Set controller with id
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?con=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]

## Set controller with slug
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?con=$1&slug=$2 [L,QSA]

## For paging
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/page/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?con=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/page/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?con=$1&slug=$2&page=$3 [L,QSA]

## Set controller for only one parameter
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?con=page&slug=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?con=$1 [L,QSA]

## Set home page
RewriteRule ^/?$ index.php?con=home [L]
```

Whenever I try to browse `http://example.com/kahuk-ajax/?prefix=manage-story-vote`, this opened the `index.php` instead of `kahuk-ajax.php`!

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your positioning of `Set Ajax Request File` seems incorrect. Try putting it after your other rules so that it gets matched last

Comment: thank you for your time and comment. I tried in the last line but no luck.

Comment: You are 90% of the way to a router script since you are sending almost everything to index.php, I’d just complete it which greatly simplifies your htaccess by moving all of the logic to PHP. You could replace everything except for the SEO and admin stuff with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54533581/231316), and then in PHP parse `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]`. This moves all complicated pattern matching into PHP which is arguably easier to read, change and test

Comment: thank you @Chris Haas. Still, i want to know why this `RewriteRule ^(kahuk-ajax)/?$ kahuk-ajax.php? [L,QSA]` is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> ## Set Ajax Request File
> RewriteRule ^(kahuk-ajax)/?$ kahuk-ajax.php? [L,QSA]
>
> :
>
> ## Set controller for only one parameter
> :
> RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?con=$1 [L,QSA]
> ```

The request is first rewritten to `kakuk-ajax.php` by the first rule, but the second to last rule then rewrites this to `index.php` during the *second pass* by the rewrite engine.

You need to prevent that second rule from rewriting requests of the form `kakuk-ajax.php`. If these URLs do not contain dots in the first path segment (that ordinarily delimits the file extension) then you could simply include a dot in the negated character class. For example:

```
## Set controller for only one parameter
:
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?con=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Alternatively, exclude specific file extensions:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(txt|json|php)$
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?con=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Or, any URL that looks like it has a file extension:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.\w{2,5}$
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?con=$1 [L,QSA]
```

---

*Aside:*

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(kahuk-ajax)/?$ kahuk-ajax.php? [L,QSA]
> ```

This rule is a little contradictory. You are removing the query string with the trailing `?`, but then appending it again with the `QSA` flag. If you wish to preserve the query string then you don't need either. And since you are capturing the URL-path, you might as well make use of this in the *substitution* string. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^(kahuk-ajax)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Also, be wary of allowing an optional trailing slash here. This promotes duplicate content which could potentially cause SEO issues. Consider redirecting one to the other instead.

> ```
> ## Allow a few SEO Files direct access.
> RewriteRule ^robots.txt?$ robots.txt [L]
> RewriteRule ^ads.txt?$ ads.txt [L]
> RewriteRule ^sellers.json?$ sellers.json [L]
> ```

The `?` at the end of the regex makes the preceding character (`t` and `n` in the above examples) optional, which does not really make sense here. Also, you don't need to rewrite to the same file - you don't want any rewrite/substitution to occur here. So, the above is the same as:

```
RewriteRule ^(robots\.txt|ads\.txt|sellers.json)$ - [L]
```

The `-` (hyphen) explicitly indicates "no substitution".

However, having included a "dot" in the (negated character class) directive above, this directive is redundant, except to "fail early".